# Need to render partial view in the place of another partial view with same layout in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to load the second partial view in the place of current partial view on click action of current partial view.

This is my main view in which table view is a first partial view.

I want to load another table (another view) on click of manage link in the place of existing partial view.
In short Master-Detail relationship of table grid view.

Below is the image for reference,
[image]

So the questions are

1) Can I do that?

2) If yes then which approach should I go for

I am trying to use the below approach but it's not working as it is loading only the second partial view without the main layout.
My main Index view,

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            User Role Management
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
        <div class="panel-body" id="Data">
            <div class="panel-body" id="divUserRoleMappingMaster">
                @Html.Partial("pv_UserRoleMappingMaster", Model)
            </div>
            @if (ViewBag.IsDetailView == "True")
            {
                <div class="panel-body" id="divManageUserRole">
                    @Html.Partial("pv_ManageUserRole", Model)
                </div>
            }

        </div>
        <!-- /.panel-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.panel -->
</div>
```

3) If any other better approach then please suggest

Comment: You use ajax to load the partial and update the DOM

Comment: to add the the above comment. http://api.jquery.com/load/ will allow you to load a partial view into a div . Just do it on a click event of your Manage button

Comment: The simplest way is loading both partials at load time and set display:none attribute of container div, and toggle this attribute by client code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is to use [@Ajax.ActionLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd460360(v=vs.118)) to load the Second Partial View.

Here the `Manage` Link is populated using `@Ajax.ActionLink` and the response content will be updated in the Target which is mentioned with `UpdateTargetId`.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Manage", 
    "pv_ManageUserRole", 
    "<CONTROLLER>", 
    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "<FIRST PARTIAL VIEW CONTAINER ID>" }
)
```

The below JS needs to be included on adding AJAX.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")"
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Alternatively, it can be done with Simple AJAX Call.

Bind the `click` event to the Manage Link and do AJAX call

```
$("<Manage Link>").click(function(){

   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: '@Url.Action("pv_ManageUserRole", "<CONTROLLER>")'
       data: '<POST Parameters if any>',
       success: function (data){
           //validate the response data and then load
           $("#<FIRST PARTIAL VIEW CONTAINER ID>").html(data);
       },
    });
});
```